# Adhoc Distribution without registering device id on portal

Tags: iphone, uuid, ad-hoc-distribution

I want adhoc distribution of app without registering Device id on the portal.So that everybody can install it on his/her device by downloading it.

On search I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5277440/1305001) and [this Link](https://developer.apple.com/programs/start/ios/) that costs about $299 for that but I am not able to understand the whole process I have to follow for this.

Can anybody explain me the entire process I have to follow for adhoc distribution for all the people not only for devices whose id is registered on portal.And let me know can we have both $99 and $299 account together or not.

Is there any limitation for number of users in $299 account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iOS Developepr Enterprise Program enrollment process 
@)https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

How the app will be distributed to the employees…

@)http://blog.blazingcloud.net/2013/01/15/testflight-versus-in-house-web-server-to-distribute-enterprise-ios-apps/
(the second option among two from this web site is the way of distribution we are going to follow.. Named: Custom Web Distribution of an Enterprise iOS App)

some more links are there you can check if that are of your use or not.

@)How to Distribute Your iOS App Without AppStore (Enterprese Distribution process)

[iPhone app without AppStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982476/iphone-app-without-appstore)

http://monkieblankie.blogspot.in/2011/03/how-to-distribute-your-ios-app-without.html
   l)http://nachbaur.com/blog/building-ios-apps-for-over-the-air-adhoc-distribution
   ll)[Can I develop an iPhone application that my company can use for internal employees only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004443/can-i-develop-an-iphone-application-that-my-company-can-use-for-internal-employe)
   lll)http://iphonecto.com/2009/09/09/deploying-internal-enterprise-application-iphone/

http://www.foraker.com/ios-app-distribution-options/

[iPhone Application Enterprise Distribution Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568360/iphone-application-enterprise-distribution-process)
 (Important link)

[Does the iPhone / iPod Touch support bulk enterprise app deployment or would all customers have to buy from app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509513/does-the-iphone-ipod-touch-support-bulk-enterprise-app-deployment-or-would-all)  (Important link)

[Alternative solutions for in-house iPhone enterprise app distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309835/alternative-solutions-for-in-house-iphone-enterprise-app-distribution/3790758#3790758)  (Important link)

http://www.maas360.com/maasters/forums/mobile-device-management-mdm/show/120/deploying-iphone-and-ipad-in-your-enterprise  (Important link)

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/9001-enterprise-iphone-application-deployment.html