# Android application for limited enterprise audience

Tags: android, deployment, google-play

This is the Android version of [App for limited or restricted audience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20088378/app-for-limited-or-restricted-audience)

### The project

I'm going to start a brand new project for one of our customers that will be deployed to our customer's *suppliers* to track on-field activity. I am skilled enough on Java/Android development so this question is **only** about deployment.

#### Owned vs provided devices

Our customer will either provide a `Samsung Galaxy Ace 4` device to the suppliers or will allow the supplier to use their own Android 4 smartphone without warranties from us. Our customer currently has a Google for Business organization set up, but we **cannot** rely on that (see partial answer).

#### Technical (non functional) requirements

- Ability to easily distribute application **and** updates across enterprise users.
- Application *should* not be visible to the public
- Application must be able to send crash reports so our team can inspect and investigate

### The question is

Given the above "*should* not be visible to the public" statement, what is the most effective and efficient way to deploy an Android app targeted only for enterprise users?
I'll post a partial answer below. I'm asking others to enrich it with other possible means, **including using Alpha/beta channels** for which I don't have experience about

Comment: question & hint: could you use another app store, or it must be Google Play store?

Comment: No, it's not required. Can you expand, maybe in the answer, with a good example? AFAIK downloading a third party app store still involves downloading an APK on every device, and privacy/security considerations *can* be discussed with the customer

Comment: At work we have different requirements and we use a custom third-party app store, but we own all the devices that use it. So I just thought it might be useful for you as well. I don't know more about the details so I cannot write it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, limited-audience Android applications can be deployed like this:

## Publishing on Google Play as a free app for the public

Maybe adding a limitation to our country

Advantages:

- Simplemost and well documented
- Auto deployes updates as soon as no new permission is enforced
- Collects crash reports on Dashboard

Disadvantages:

- Everyone can download the app

  - This has the disadvantage that some organizations may not be happy as publicly available code might in some cases help exploit vulnerabilites on remote systems (but it is almost impossible if app is well-written and obfuscated)
- If country limitation is enforced, imported devices won't download

## Distributing the APK direct URL

Advantages:

- The app remains private (enterprise users are **surely** not going to redistribute the app to friends as it's no use without enterprise credentials)

Disadvantages:

- No crash reports unless implementing a third-party library
- No auto updates unless implemented by custom code or third party library. Implementing auto updates prevents the app from being published to Google Play in the future, even on a private channel, as Play prohibits apps that auto-update themselves via third-party channels. Or, to be precise, the auto-update feature and Play publishing require, in order to exist together, maintaining two APKs

## Google Play for Enterprise

As mentioned on [this link](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en), Google Play provides a private channel for app deploying for users withing a Google for Business organization. This is **the** perfect approach for applications that organization's users must use

Advantages:

- Same as publishing for the public (simple, auto update, crash report)
- Visible only to restricted audience

Disadvantages:

- Every device must come with a Google account within the organization, and it will be economically unfeasible to [request the Sysadmin to] enable Google accounts for every **external** supplier in our target organization

## Permanently in Alpha/Beta

I haven't tested this yet, as it is also very tricky. Basically, it involves using [testing mode](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en&ref_topic=3450986) without ever going to production. With Google Play, one can deploy artifacts into Alpha (e.g. *test server environment*) and Beta (a trick to point to *production server environment*) without **ever** moving the app to Google Play's Production stage.

All requires setting up special moderated Google+ groups

Potential advantages:

- Same as publishing to enterprise

Disadvantages:

- Only telling users to subscribe to Google+ and joining a community

Comment: Regarding your disadvantage for distributing the APK direct URL, you mention there are no crash reports. However, you probably should instead mention that there's no crash reports *by default* unless you use a third party library. There are plenty of services that provide both auto-updating and/or crash report management.

Comment: Updated the answer. I must expand the auto-update part for the hybrid approach. In a few words, auto-update from third party excludes the app from being ever published to a Play private channel. I must take this into consideration (my question is about effectiveness and efficiency of deploument)

Answer (score 1):

From your requirements, I would suggest **distributing the APK via a direct URL** and integrating a service such as HockeyApp (see their [Android SDK](http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-android-other-platforms/hockeyapp-for-android-sdk) for more) to manage *both* the crash reports and app updates.

- *"Ability to easily distribute application and updates across enterprise users"*

  Many services allow `.apk` files to be uploaded directly to their service for deployment. A direct download link is then generated for that build.

  Crash information is collected and updates are automatically displayed *if* the app implements the Android SDK provided by the service.
- *"Application should not be visible to the public"*

  Services such as HockeyApp do not publicise direct download links publicly. This link can therefore be distributed as required.
- *"Application must be able to send crash reports so our team can inspect and investigate"*

  **Full** stack-trace and device information is sent along with crash reports and can be viewed online by technicians.

From my experience there are a few pros and cons:

- **Pros**:

  - App distribution is super easy, as simple as visiting a website.
  - Bug reports are comparable to those received through Google Play
- **Cons**:

  - Crash report's aren't sent automatically and updates aren't automatic

    By default, updates and crashes appear as system dialogs prompting users to either send the crash report/update the app *or* cancel. Ideally, no user interaction should be required to perform the desired actions. I am sure it is possible but have not found relevant documentation for it.
  - Cost. These services aren't free.
  - Would require the removal of the service SDK from the app if uploaded to Play Store